# jQuery image rotator

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make this simple image rotator but, as usual, my code doesn't work. I want to swap between 2 images ("image1" and "image2")

```
$x = 0;
function rotateImage(){
    if($x == 0){  //if function is being called for the first time
        $x = 1;
    }
    $(".window").html("<img src=\"../images/image" + $x + ".png\" />");
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x > 2)  
        $x = 1;  //reset x to 1 if last image has been reached
}

rotateImage();  //first function call
setInterval("rotateImage()", 1000);  //call function every second
```

Image1 shows up but there is no swapping going on.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

You don't need dollar signs in javascript for variables, and x as an integer doesn't add well with strings.  Try this and let me know if you have any issues:

```
var x = '0'; 
function rotateImage(){ 
    if (x == '0') { x = '1'; } else { x = '0'; }
    $(".window").html("<img src=\"../images/image" + x + ".png\" />"); 
} 

rotateImage();  //first function call 
setInterval("rotateImage()", 1000);  //call function every second
```

Also.. are you sure that ".window" is the proper selector to use for the image container?  I recommend having the image in a DIV with an ID and using "#theID" as a selector.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. In response to your other question, I have a div with class "window" (which, come to think of it, is a rather poor name).

Comment: Where are the last two lines of code being executed? Is it in the document.ready/onload function?

Comment: Yes, all of the above code is in the document.ready function.

Comment: Try taking the function out, having it by itself.

Comment: Tried that too...I think I'm just going to get a plug-in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more of an example, or a public URL?  It's most likely that you're making a very small mistake.

Comment: Div:

    <div class="window">
    </div>

javascript:

    var x = "1"; 
 function rotateImage(){ 
  if (x == "1") { x = "2"; } else { x = "1"; }
  $(".window").html("<img src=\"../images/image" + x  + ".png\" />"); 
 }
        rotateImage();  //first function call 
 setInterval("rotateImage()", 1000);  //call function every second

This is exactly as it appears in my files

Comment: sorry, i can't have extra spaces and linebreaks so that's why it looks cluttered

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work, but I still suspect some other issue.  just for troubleshooting, replace setInterval with setTimeout.  if that doesn't work, open FireBug and run rotateImage(); from the console.  if that doesn't work, then the issue is completely unrelated.